# IntelliJ IDEA complains about "implicit numeric conversion of char to int"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA complains about this code:

```
char c = 'A';
if (c == 'B') return;
```

The warning is on the second line:

```
Implicit numeric conversion from char to int
```

What does it mean? What does it expect me to do?

Comment: Does not occur in Eclipse, maybe a wrongful implementation in IntelliJ? Or warning levels are set very high in your IDE?

Comment: With Idea 13 it does not produce any warning.

Comment: You should turn on "Numeric Issues/Implicit numeric conversion" inspection. However, I'm not interested to get rid of the warning. I want to understand what is it about and improve my code

Comment: According to this it doesn't make a difference usually, it's just there in the slight off chance it would. I'm not entirely sure where the `int` comes from though. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp

Comment: Are you sure that it's correct warning? All I'm getting is that the expression is always false.

Comment: My guess is this: when comparing two chars, it just compares their int value.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation for this is hidden in the JLS. It states that `==` is a [numerical operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1). If you read the text and follow some links you can find out that `char` is converted to `int`. It never says explicitly that this happens also if both operands are `char` but it [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

```
Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:

* If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

* Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.

* Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.

* Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
```

I think the last one implicitly means that `char` is always converted. Also in [another section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) it says `"If either operand is not an int, it is first widened to type int by numeric promotion."`.

The warning you are getting might be very strict, but it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably safer to use the static `Character.compare(char x, char y)` method instead of using `==`.

I haven't found anything in the JLS or in the JavaDoc, but there could be potential unicode bugs using your method.  The warning you posted suggested that your chars could be widened to ints which could possibly create a performance issue, but I really doubt that.  I'll keep searching because now I'm interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

All chars are translated to int by compilator. You can even do this:

```
char a = 'b';  
int one = a - 46;// it's 40 something...
```

You can get rid of this warning by casting your character to int.

```
char c = 'A';
if (c == (int)'B') return;
```

or

you can use `Character` object and use `equal` method to compare it.

Comment: This is not quite correct. A `char` is a 16 bit unsingned integer (integer meaning a numeric value, not to be confused with `int`) while `int` is a 32 bit signed integer. `char` can be used in arethmic expressions together with `int` because of [numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6), which happens at runtime, not compile time.